# What "where" clause will make this Generic Method work?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider this admittedly contrived Generic Definition:

```
    private void Foo<T,BASETYPE>(PropertyInfo prop, BASETYPE o1, BASETYPE o2)
    {
        T value1 = (T) prop.GetValue(o1, null);
        T value2 = (T) prop.GetValue(o2, null);
        if (value1 != value2)
            Console.WriteLine("NOT EQUAL");
    }
```

prop is guaranteed to be a PropertyInfo for BASETYPE.

I am getting a compile error at the if() statement:

```
Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

While in the "general case" I understand that the error message is valid, in this case, I only want the routine for some of the standard types: System.Int64, System.String, etc all of which support the == and != operator.

I assume this can be fixed with a "where" clause, but IComparable and IEqualable don't help.

Do anyone know what the correct "where" clause is?

Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since System.Int64, System.String, etc .. from your list implement `IComparable`, you could use

```
where T : IComparable
```

and use `CompareTo()` instead of `!=`

For eg. this code would compile

```
private void Foo<T>(object o) where T : IComparable
{
    T v1 = default(T);
    T v2 = default(T);
    if(v1.CompareTo(v2)  != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
    }
}

private void Bar()
{
    Foo<string>(new object());
}
```

Comment: This is more specific than the code needs to be.  `IEquatable` is all you need.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessary restriction on the type when you really don't need the ordering capabilities of IComparable.

Comment: @Matt @luqui - Don't both interfaces limit your choices? I think you both agree that IEquatable is for comparing, and IComparable is for sorting. If your type implements one and not the other you end up filtering your available objects no matter what?

Comment: @Ritch: You don't need a where clause at all to solve this problem.

Comment: @Matt Right. Just .Equals(). That's what I had in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one, unfortunately.  You need to use `.Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Equals()` instance method that all types have, the static `Object.ReferenceEquals()` or `Object.Equals()` methods, or you could use the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to accept a performance hit, you can use

```
if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value1, value2) == 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("NOT EQUAL");
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I've never seen that before. What causes the performance hit? Why not use object.Equals?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. There's no such thing as an operator constraint, so there's no way to tell the compiler that it should only allow objects with the != operator to be called. You can use the .Equals method because that's in the base object class.

Here's an article discussing operator constraints:
[Operator Constraints](http://en.csharp-online.net/Understanding_Generics%E2%80%94The_Lack_of_Operator_Constraints)